# add average value to every row containing value in different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with ages (int) and wages, I would like to have the average wage next to each row of a person respective of that age.

I created a smaller dataset using
`mean = df.groupby('age', as_index=False)['lnWage'].mean()`

what is the best way to append (for 2000 rows)?

| Age | Wage |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 10 |
| 30 | 20 |

then

| Age | Wage | averagewage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 10 | 15 |
| 30 | 20 | 15 |

thanks!

Comment: `df['averagewage'] = df.groupby('Age')['Wage'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above are helpful, I have found this to be the easiest method, where average is the df with average wages. (ffr)

`df_main['avgWage'] = df['age'].map(average_df['averageWage'])`

Answer (score 0):

[Michael Szczensny's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny) comment seems to address your issue well. If it doesn't, I would propose creating another method that could be used to identify the average wage by age using your average wage dataframe as well.

Kind of like this example:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/